# Building GDB12.1 using msys2 with GCC11.3

Tags: build, gdb, msys2

I am using msys64 with GCC11.3 on a Win 10 64 bit machine to build GDB12.1 with:

```
$GDB_SRCDIR/$GDB_VERSION/configure --target=$TARGET --with-expat=yes --enable-static=yes --with-python> configure.log 2>&1
make > make.log 2>&1
```

My host is **x86_64-w64-mingw32** and my target is **i686-elf**

I need to deliver only GDB with Python support, without installing msys64 on the customers machine. When I start GDB, with enabled msys64 I get correct GDB:

[image: GDB12.1]

I also have a preinstalled GDB10.1 from another package with current settings:

[image: GDB10.1]

Notice on GDB10.1: it works without having python installed localy.

What I need is the option to build GDB12.1 with settings from GDB10.1, instead as in GDB12.1

```
--with-python=C:/msys64/mingw64
--with-python-libdir=C:/msys64/mingw64/lib
```

I need following as in GDB10.1:

```
--with-python=/mingw64 (relocatable)
--with-python-libdir=/mingw64/lib (relocatable)
```

I have an start script for starting GDB12.1 with following code:

```
python
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert (0, "\\Python")
sys.path.append ("\\lib")
sys.path.append ("\\share")

end
```

In my installation I have following folders:

```
bin - containing built GDB with needed DLLS
lib - containing libraries from Python 3.9.12 installation
Python - containing GDB and libstdcxx support scripts
share - containing support from GCC11.3
```

The folder structure is following:

```
->gdb-12.1
-->bin
-->lib
-->Python
-->share
```

When I rename msys64, and I try to start GDB12.1 I got following error:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'c:\msys64\mingw64/bin/python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'c:\\msys64\\mingw64/bin/python'
  sys.base_prefix = 'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'c:\\msys64\\mingw64/bin/python'
  sys.prefix = 'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.path = [
    'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\python39.zip',
    'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\python3.9',
    'D:\\a\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\lib-dynload',
    '',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000a5a0 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

What do I want, or need? I want to build GDB12.1 with flags as in the distributed GDB10.1:

```
--with-python=/mingw64 (relocatable)
--with-python-libdir=/mingw64/lib (relocatable)
```

How should I build GDB12.1 to get those options??
Or, is there any other way to get Python support inside GDB12.1 without installed Python?
The problem that I have is, when connecting to a target, by building GDB which is built --with-python=C:\Python39\, and disabling C:\Python39 and C:\msys64, GDB12.1 works, but I can not send CTRL+C to GDB, which is essential to the work that has to be done. Is there a way to send CTRL+C to GDB??
Any help would be nice.

Comment: Did you not set `--prefix` in the configure call? To get python `relocatable` its path needs to be within the prefix path.

Comment: I have found a solution for my problem: 
1. do not install locally python, you do not need it, the correct version is already installed in msys2. If you needed a newer version update python directly in msys2
2. using following flags: 
--with-python=Python --with-python-libdir=lib 
you can get a GDB which has everything needed and can be started without installed msys2 or python.

You need folowing structure: 
folder/bin/gdb.exe and related needed dlls from msys64/mingw64/bin 
folder/lib/python3.9 
folder/share/gcc-11.3.0 
folder/share/gdb